# c++: how to get c#-like properties

Tags: c++, properties

Is it possible to have c#-like properties in c++? At first I thought not and I have,'t found any source that claims it has this.

But I found a header file (that seems to be written in c# at first but it's actually c++) and in that file it seems to declare properties with a property keyword:

```
property Boolean AlphaToCoverageEnable
{
    Boolean get()
    {
        return alphaToCoverageEnable;
    }

    void set(Boolean value)
    {
        alphaToCoverageEnable = value;
    }
}
```

I tried to use this in eclipse but it didn't like it... Is there a way to do this? A header I need to include or a something to do with how it compiles?

The file I found: 
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/847423/D3D10Structs.h

Comment: D3D10... It's probably an MSVC extension like `interface`.

Comment: C++ does not have properties, and there is no way to implement them without at least some cost in writing extra code and spending some memory.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at C++/CLI, which is a Microsoft extension to C++ that adds .Net support.

C++ does not support properties, but you can make things that act like properties by abusing operator overloads.

For example, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534994.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, C++ (the language) does not support C#-style properties. Properties are implemented with two functions: a setter, and a getter. Even C# properties are translated at the CLI-level into setter/getter functions.

It appears that the Microsoft C++/CLI extensions to the C++ language supports C#-style properties but the ANSI standard C++ language does not.

Answer (score 0):

This is C++/CLI, not standard C++.  C++/CLI supports properties since it's intended to work seamlessly with .NET concepts.

You can tell directly in the `public value struct BlendDescription` class declaration - the `value struct` defines a C++/CLI value type (`struct` in C#).

Answer (score 0):

I've used the code from this CodeGuru project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118921/C-Properties

Using that I created a "properties.h" file containing this:

```
#define PROPERTY(t,n)  __declspec( property 
( put = property__set_##n, get = property__get_##n ) ) t n;\
typedef t property__tmp_type_##n
#define READONLY_PROPERTY(t,n) __declspec( property (get = property__get_##n) ) t n;\
typedef t property__tmp_type_##n
#define WRITEONLY_PROPERTY(t,n) __declspec( property (put = property__set_##n) ) t n;\
typedef t property__tmp_type_##n
#define GET(n) property__tmp_type_##n property__get_##n() 
#define SET(n) void property__set_##n(const property__tmp_type_##n& value)
```

with an example property being:

```
PROPERTY(LatLonAltTuple, LatLonAlt);
GET(LatLonAlt) { return m_LatLonAlt; }
SET(LatLonAlt) { m_LatLonAlt = value; }
```